# Remove string within certain characters

Tags: python, string, list

If i have a string such as

> string = "This text is &This text is also unknown &unknown to the program"

How do i remove everything within the & character?

Comment: What have you tried doing?

Comment: if char == "<":
            removemode = True
        if removemode == True:
            pass
        if removemode == False:
            newline.append(char)
        if char == ">":
            removemode = False

Comment: also at the start is "for char in line:" then a "newline" lsit is being created with the new values

Comment: `re.sub('&.+&', '', string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach using [find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

```
s = "This text is &This text is also unknown &unknown to the program"

start = s.find('&')
end = s.find('&', start+1)
result = s[:start] + s[end+1:]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
This text is unknown to the program
```

Comment: Good call with not having to import anything.

Answer (score 2):

You could use regedit to remove it (I assume you also want `&` gone):

```
import re
string = "This text is &This text is also unknown &unknown to the program"
sEdit = re.sub('&.*&', '', string)
print(sEdit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or `replace`+`find`:

```
print(string.replace(string[string.find('&'):string.find('&',string.find('&')+1)+1],''))
```

Output:

```
This text is unknown to the program
```